# how to call validation data from keras's ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm studying the MNIST dataset, and decided to try datageneration. Now directly:

I'm generating data using validation split as follows:

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(... , validation_split=0.21, ...)

datagen.fit(train_x)
```

but i don't know hot to call the validation split of this into the model's fit

```
hist = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(train_x, train_y, batch_size =32), 
                                steps_per_epoch=len(train_x)//32, 
                                epochs = 70, verbose=0, callbacks= [PlotLossesKeras()], 
                                validation_data= **???**, <-----
                                validation_steps=None, 
                                validation_freq=1, 
                                class_weight=None, 
                                max_queue_size=10, 
                                workers=1, 
                                use_multiprocessing=False, 
                                shuffle=True,
                                initial_epoch=0)
```

I couldn't find an answer in the documentation nor elsewhere. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should state which subset you are using: `subset = 'validation'`, as the [Keras documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#flow) says:

> subset: Subset of data ("training" or "validation") if validation_split is set in ImageDataGenerator.

So, for example, you could do as follows:

```
datagen = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(..., validation_split=0.21)

train_generator = datagen.flow(..., subset='training')
valid_generator = datagen.flow(..., subset='validation')

hist = model.fit_generator(...,
        generator = train_generator,
        validation_data = valid_generator,
        steps_per_epoch = len(train_generator),
        validation_steps = len(valid_generator),
)
```

You can see some examples provided by Keras itself as well, right after `ImageDataGenerator class` [documentation](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)